# typedef: When I put a strings into the structure, top variable contains bottom variables' strings in C

Tags: c, typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct{
    char a[10];
    char b[1];
    char c[5];
    char d[8];
}T_TEMP_C;

int main()
{
    char* temp = "123456789012345678901234";
    T_TEMP_C* ltpa = (T_TEMP_C*) temp;


    printf("ltpa -> a : %s\n", ltpa->a);
    printf("ltpa -> b : %c\n", ltpa->b[0]);
    printf("ltpa -> c : %s\n", ltpa->c);
    printf("ltpa -> d : %s\n", ltpa->d);

    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
    ltpa -> a : 123456789012345678901234                                                                                                                                               
    ltpa -> b : 1                                                                                                                                                                      
    ltpa -> c : 2345678901234                                                                                                                                                          
    ltpa -> d : 78901234
```

I don't understand why this happens.

why char a contains the whole string even though size of a is only 10.

I want to contain 1234567890 to a
1 to b, 23456 to c, and rest to d

Answer (score 1):

`%s` formatting prints the string until it gets to a null terminator. The only terminator in `temp` is at the very end, not after each substring. If you want this to work, you need to embed null bytes at the appropriate places, and increase the array sizes in the structure to accomodate them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct{
    char a[11];
    char b[1];
    char c[6];
    char d[9];
}T_TEMP_C;

int main()
{
    char* temp = "1234567890\0123456\078901234";
    T_TEMP_C* ltpa = (T_TEMP_C*) temp;

    printf("ltpa -> a : %s\n", ltpa->a);
    printf("ltpa -> b : %c\n", ltpa->b[0]);
    printf("ltpa -> c : %s\n", ltpa->c);
    printf("ltpa -> d : %s\n", ltpa->d);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm not even sure that your type punning is really defined to work. Implementations are allowed to add padding between structure members, so there's no guarantee that `b` will start immediately after `a`.

If you don't want to change `temp`, then you can't use `%s` format to print the substrings. You can specify a precision in the format string, then it will only print that many bytes of the string. `%.10s` will print up to 10 bytes, rather than until the null terminator.

```
    printf("ltpa -> a : %.10s\n", ltpa->a);
    printf("ltpa -> b : %c\n", ltpa->b[0]);
    printf("ltpa -> c : %.5s\n", ltpa->c);
    printf("ltpa -> d : %s\n", ltpa->d);
```

Comment: I don't want to change "temp"

Comment: @JaceCho, though this may not be the answer you hoped for, your original post expressed that you didn't understand why your program was behaving the way it was.  This does answer your question.

Comment: @JaceCho I've amended the answer to show how you can specify the number of bytes to print in the format strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against casting a `char` pointer to a `struct` pointer.

To accomplish your goal, you can use `snprintf`.  I.e.,

```
const char* temp = "123456789012345678901234";
T_TEMP_C thing;

snprintf(thing.a,sizeof(thing.a), "%.*s", 10, temp);
snprintf(thing.b,sizeof(thing.b), "%.*s", 1, temp+10);
snprintf(thing.c,sizeof(thing.c), "%.*s", 5, temp+11);
snprintf(thing.d,sizeof(thing.d), "%s", temp+16);
```